# How to select for the longest match from regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a long string that I need to split into separate strings. I have written up a regex pattern shown below. The problem right now is that my long string is split into the smaller strings but with duplicates.

That is what my code looks like:

```
import re

teststring = '''#first-error-type: cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k, 
#second-err, #some-other-error : jksdf89-123r-e3-1345r, 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k 
#third-errortype cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k, ksdf89-123r-e3-1345r, 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k'
'''

new = re.sub('\((.+)\)', '', teststring)
#remove perenthesis
new = re.sub(':', '', new)
#removing stray colons
new = re.sub(r'([#][\w]*(-[\w]*)*[,]*)', r'\1:', new)
#adding colons

new = re.split(r'(([#][\w]*)*(-[\w]*)*[, :]([\w]*[-, ]*)*)', new)
```

Due to the inconsistencies of the text, I have to do preliminary cleaning in the beginning to remove stray colons and then add it in later

Currently, this is my output:

```
['', '#first-error-type: cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k, ', '#first', '-type', '', '\n', '#second-err,', '#second', '-err', '', '', ': ', None, None, '', '', '#some-other-error:  jksdf89-123r-e3-1345r , 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k ', '#some', '-error', '', '\n', '#third-errortype: cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k, ksdf89-123r-e3-1345r, 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k', '#third', '-errortype', '', "'\n"]
```

The code I am expecting is:

```
['#first-error-type: cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k',  
'#second-err, #some-other-error: jksdf89-123r-e3-1345r (some kind of note), 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k',
'#third-errortype: cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k, ksdf89-123r-e3-1345r, 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k']
```

It seems like I had made a few mistakes in the pattern so I am not grouping two hashtag comments together to add just one colon. Also, the output is split into duplicating segments of varing length.

Comment: Try `new = re.sub(r'[^\S\n]+(:)|,[^\S\n]*(?=\n)', r'\1', teststring)` and then `print( re.findall(r'#\w+(?:-\w+)*[,: ].*', new) )`, see https://ideone.com/6toBPy

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you! This is so close, but it doesn't add the ":" correctly to the third hashtag, resulting in a weird double quotation outside of a single quote.

Comment: Please check https://ideone.com/6toBPy

Comment: I see that the colon is added to the third line hashtag but the single and double quotation mark is still there.

Comment: Ok, try `print( list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.findall(r'#\w+(?:-\w+)*[,: ][^"\'\r\n]*', new))) )`, see https://ideone.com/6toBPy

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
 
teststring = '''#first-error-type: cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k, 
#second-err, #some-other-error : jksdf89-123r-e3-1345r (some kind of note), 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k 
#third-errortype cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k, ksdf89-123r-e3-1345r, 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k'
'''
new = re.sub(
    r'(#\w+(?:-\w+)*)(?=[:\s]+\w)[^\S\n]*(?::[^\S\n]*)?|,[^\S\n]*(?=\n)', 
    lambda x: f'{x.group(1)}: ' if x.group(1) else '',
    teststring)
print( list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.findall(r'#\w+(?:-\w+)*[,: ][^"\'\r\n]*', new))) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6toBPy).

Output:

```
['#first-error-type: cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k', '#second-err, #some-other-error: jksdf89-123r-e3-1345r (some kind of note), 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k', '#third-errortype: cjjyr901-d374-jfh73kf8k, ksdf89-123r-e3-1345r, 99f7yr901-374-jfh73kf8k']
```

The `(#\w+(?:-\w+)*)(?=[:\s]+\w)[^\S\n]*(?::[^\S\n]*)?|,[^\S\n]*(?=\n)` regex matches

- `(#\w+(?:-\w+)*)(?=[:\s]+\w)[^\S\n]*(?::[^\S\n]*)?` -

  - `(#\w+(?:-\w+)*)` - Group 1: a `#` char followed with one or more word chars followed with zero or more repetitions of a `-` and again one or more word chars
  - `(?=[:\s]+\w)` - there must be a word char after any one or more whitespaces or `:` from the location
  - `[^\S\n]*`  - zero or more whitespaces but LF char
  - `(?::[^\S\n]*)?` - an optional occurrence of a `:` and zero or more whitespaces but LF char
- `|` - or
- `,[^\S\n]*(?=\n)` - a comma, zero or more whitespaces but LF char followed with an LF char

The match is removed if Group 1 is not matched, else, we return Group 1 plus a colon with a space.

The `#\w+(?:-\w+)*[,: ][^"\'\r\n]*` regex used in `re.findall` matches

- `#\w+(?:-\w+)*` - a `#`, one or more word chars, and zero or more occurrences of a `-` and one or more word chars
- `[,: ]` - a space, comma or colon
- `[^"\'\r\n]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`, `'`, CR and LF.

The `map(lambda x: x.strip(),...)` is used to stip whitespaces mainly from the end of the matches since the `[^"\'\r\n]*` negated character class can match them at will.